# Custom path generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes, helper

I thought I knew how to override a path helper, but I'm not getting my expected behavior.

I tried adding something like this to my ApplicationHelper:

```
def post_path(post)
  "/posts/#{post.id}/#{post.url}"
end
```

But for some reason, in one of my controllers when I try to use `post_path(@post)` it just returns the full url, something like `/posts/4faddb375d9a1e045e000068/asdf` (which is the current url in the browser) rather than `/posts/4faddb375d9a1e045e000068/post-title-here`.

In my routes file:

`get '/posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#show', :as => 'post'`

The strange thing is if I use `post_path(@post, @post.url)`, it works correctly. And if in a view I use `post_path(@post)` it works correctly. (`@post.url` returns the url friendly title)

In case you can't tell, I'm trying to eventually get the behavior similar to stackoverflow's where the url contains the id and a slug at the end and if the slug doesn't match the model with the given id, it'll redirect to the correct url.

Comment: where do you define 'post.url'?

Comment: post.url is a method on the model and returns the title of the post in a url friendly way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd try would be to put the whole `def post_path` in the `application_controller.rb` and make it a helper with `helper_method :post_path`.  You'll get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Would be wonderful to see a solution that injects the path directly into `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`